# How to Iterate IEnumerable in mvc 5 View without foreach or for loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating questionnaire application, in which I have to load random questions and get answers from the user. 
I want to know, How I should iterate the records using the button. 
I know how to display the data using foreach/for loop on the view, but the requirement is I have to display one question at a time, get the answer, store it in list, and when user press the "Next" button, I have to present the next question record to the user.
I would appreciate any help in this regard.
Thanks. 
I have attached my sample code here:

VIEW MODEL CLASS:

```
public class ExamViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Question> QuestionsList { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }

    public Question GetQuestionAtIndex(IEnumerable<Question> questionsList, int index = 0)
    {
        return questionsList.ElementAt(index);
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
<h2>@Model.Heading</h2>
<div class="panel-body">
        @{
            int index = 0;
            var question = Model.GetQuestionAtIndex(Model.QuestionsList, index);
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-heading list-group-item-warning">
                        @question.QuestionText
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you doing this all in javascript or do you want to submit the answer to the server each time?

Comment: I want to store each answer result in list, and submit that list at the end of whole test. (lets say after 10 questions)

Comment: That sounds more like just storing the answers in an array in javascript, then submitting that at the end via either form submission or ajax.  You will probably want to load all of the questions in the beginning and use jquery to show/hide the individual questions as you go.

Comment: thanks a lot for the guidance, can you guide me by showing some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic outline:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/xKdwlK

In that example I just load all of the answers into an array and used ajax to send it to the controller.  I didn't write the controller save method because I have no idea what you need there but you can fill that in.

This is just one way to do it but you could also use a form submission instead of ajax.

Comment: Clicking on your link yields a    Error 404. Page not found  !

Comment: Here is the link:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/xKdwlK
I got it from the edit section.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. 
I will add modifications to it. :)

Comment: I had an update that fixed the bootstrap stuff but appraently it didn't save.